# Как получить uncompressed byte array (DirectShow)?

Tags: c++, directshow

Я использую `DirectShow` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow для того, чтоб проигрывать `.mp3` стрим. У меня есть вот такая имплементация

```
bool coAudioPlayer::LoadImp(SoundDataType dataType, std::string const & filename, unsigned char const * pData, int64_t dataLen, bool bOnlyIfFilenameChanged)
{
...
    m_pMemReader = new CMemReader(m_pMemStream, m_pMediaType, &hr);

    m_pMemReader->AddRef();


    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IGraphBuilder,
        (void **)&this->m_pigb);

    hr = m_pigb->AddFilter(m_pMemReader, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    m_pigb->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&m_pimc);
    m_pigb->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEventEx, (void **)&m_pimex);
    m_pigb->QueryInterface(IID_IBasicAudio, (void**)&m_piba);
    m_pigb->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaSeeking, (void**)&m_pims);

    /*  Render our output pin */
    hr = m_pigb->Render(m_pMemReader->GetPin(0));
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    HRESULT hr = m_pimc->Run();

    return m_bReady;
}
```

Но мне нужно добавить возможность получения декодированного стрима. Насколько я понимаю `DirectShow` декодит это внутри, так вот вопрос в том если можно эту декодинг дату как то получить?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nf-strmif-imeminputpin-receive

Comment: @user7860670 это интерфейс я так понял больше связан с input , вроде нужно делать кастомную реализацию фильтра

Comment: "нужно делать кастомную реализацию фильтра" - нужно, в windows sdk есть примеры по использованию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я уже [ответил на большом StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895725/868014)... То, что вам посоветовали делать фильтр - так тоже можно, но не [обязательно] нужно. С учётом того, что вы задаёте тот вопрос, который задали, сделать фильтр будет где-то на порядок сложнее, но с тем же конечным результатом.

Еще один пример того, как используется Sample Grabber: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34663/DirectShow-Examples-for-Using-SampleGrabber-for-Gr Вторая часть посвящена аудио.

UPD. Тракты воспроизведения состоят из фильтров, и, соответственно, нужно или использовать имеющиеся или писать свой. Связка Sample Grabber + Null Renderer даёт возможность не делать свой фильтр и посредством callback'а получать доступ к данным. Актуальный формат данных можно настроить посредством настройки фильтра Sample Grabber.

Сам Sample Grabber отмечен как deprecated/устаревший. Это - так, но всё же он присутствует во всех текущих версиях Windows за исключением UWP приложений, где DirectShow API не будет уже никогда.

- [Using the Sample Grabber](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/using-the-sample-grabber)

Comment: О супер, тут намного проще:) спасибо! Как я писал мне нужно добавить возможность получать декодированую дату без ее проигрывания. Раньше не работал с декодерами и эта статья кажется запутаной, я не совсем понял где там есть доступ к декодированной дате. Еще раз посмотрю

Comment: Но в целом сампл грабер кажется правильным решением. Тут в документации есть строчка `If you want to retrieve samples without rendering the data, connect the Sample Grabber filter to the Null Renderer filter` это то, что мне нужно

Comment: Я добавил к ответу ^^^ и хочу отметить что за 25 лет по использованию Sample Grabber накопилось приличное количество материалов. Попробуйте что-то подходящее найти поиском, а если нет, то напишите на чём запнулись.

Comment: Я создал новый проект и теперь хочу сделать имплементацию этого интерфейса  ISampleGrabber, следуя документации я попробовал скачать sdk так как хедеры этого интерфейса только в определенной версии win skd, но там я тоже наткнулся , что нужно сначала скачать `.NET 4 framework`, когда его пробую установить получаю сообщение о том, что у меня это уже есть. вот тут опубликовал вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/64912751/5709159 , как это можно решить?